# NodeJS: Sharing Application State Between Modules

Tags: node.js

I am working on a node.js application that is intended to be globally installed using npm. I am using [commander](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander) in order to expose multiple commands to the command line. i.e. `my-app serve` and `my-app clean`. The problem I'm running into is that there is some data that I want all of my JS files in my `lib` directory to have access to, however from what I can tell, I should be avoiding the `global` object.

Here is the solution I came up with:

In my `lib` directory, I have a file named `shared-state.js`. Its contents:

```
var initialized = false;

var SHAREDSTATE = module.exports = {
    init: function( stateToShare ) {
        if ( !initialized ) {
            SHAREDSTATE.data = stateToShare;
            initialized = true;
        } else {
            // log warning about calling init > 1 time
        }
        return SHAREDSTATE;
    }
};
```

As long as I call init during my application's start-up, I can write the following code to get access to the shared data.

```
var sharedState = require('./shared-state').data;
```

This is a distilled example to illustrate the pattern I am following. In reality I am taking steps to make the data read-only for any modules that are consuming it, and I am appropriately handling the case where init is called multiple times.

**My question is this:** Am I crazy for going to these lengths to avoid the `global` object? Is this an established pattern in node? What is it called? If it is not, how are other people solving a similar issue?

Comment: Do you still need a solution to this question, bro?