# Share data between modules in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am working on a home automation project in NodeJS with several modules. These modules need access to data devices within a central `DeviceManager`. Normally I would create a singleton for this purpose so all modules access the same state of the `DeviceManager`.

To create a singleton I use:

```
class DevicesManagerInstance {

    constructor() {

        this.devices = {};

    }

    addDevice(id, device) {
        this.devices.id = device;
    }

}

let DevicesManagerInstance = new DevicesManager();

module.exports = DevicesManagerInstance;
```

I've found some older questions regarding singletons and sharing data but still not satisfied with the answer to the question if it is de NodeJS way to share data:

- https://derickbailey.com/2016/03/09/creating-a-true-singleton-in-node-js-with-es6-symbols/
- [Singleton pattern in nodejs - is it needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179109/singleton-pattern-in-nodejs-is-it-needed)
- [NodeJS: Sharing Application State Between Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977569/nodejs-sharing-application-state-between-modules)

But also read singletons are an anti-pattern. Can someone clarify what is the "NodeJS" way of sharing data between modules (in my case the devices). In Angular I would create a service for this purpose.

Comment: Is DevicesManager going to be in the same process as everything else?

Comment: Yes it is, the thing is that I have lots of modules all needed to access the same device data.

Comment: Then what you have is completely fine! Good luck :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why fix what isn't broken? If your approach works, it works.

That being said, I don't see any reason to create a class if I'm only going to create one instance. I would opt for a different approach:

```
var DeviceManager = {
    devices: {},
    addDevice(id, device) { // this is valid syntax
        DeviceManager.devices[id] = device;
    }
};
module.exports = DeviceManager;
```

or, if you don't want devices to be available outside of the module:

```
var devices = {};
var DeviceManager = {
    addDevice(id, device) { // this is valid syntax
        devices[id] = device;
    }
};
module.exports = DeviceManager;
```

Comment: What about the constructor part. My example is simplified in the real class there a lot of operations and initialisation going on. Do you just create for example a init function?

Comment: Why create an init function when the only time you'll be initializing something is when you're defining it? Personally, I would initialize everything when I defined DeviceManager.

Answer (score 2):

This is a single instance but if you need class you can also convert the following to class structure easily,

```
var DeviceManager = function() {
      this.devices: [];  // constructor
};

DeviceManager.prototype.addDevice = function(id, device) {
             DeviceManager.devices[id] = device;          
};
var deviceManager = new DeviceManager();
module.exports = deviceManager;
```

You can access the **devices**  in other modules as

```
var DeviceManager = require('./devicemanager');
DeviceManager.devices; // accessing devices
```

Comment: What about the constructor part. My example is simplified in the real class there a lot of operations and initialisation going on. Do you just create for example a init function?

Comment: I have updated the script @BasvanDijk You now have access to that instance and there is only one **DeviceManager** instance.